# I need to run a script every time I open WSL Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10

Tags: sh, startup, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Every time I open WSL Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 I want to run these settings automatically.

```
    alias desktop='cd /mnt/c/Users/Dot/Desktop/ai_files'
    export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/ai-safety-gridworlds
    export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

I tried making .sh script with the following content in /etc/init.d/   but it didn't work.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    alias desktop='cd /mnt/c/Users/Dot/Desktop/ai_files'
    export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/ai-safety-gridworlds
    export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

Comment: If you want a scrit to run each time a shell is created, you can add it to your `.bashrc` (assuming you are using bash).

Comment: You are awesome!
Added my 3 lines of code to bash.bashrc in /etc/ and it runs them on every Ubuntu start. I used Microsoft Store to install Ubuntu 18.04 and using the shortcut that it made, I assume its bash.

Comment: The .bashrc file is in your home directory `cd ~`

Comment: Is it possible to create a cron job? If yes then that will be the easiest way to run any timed task.

Answer (score 5):

To run these commands every time you open [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), you will want to append the commands to [`.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work).
In bash, run

```
echo "alias desktop='cd /mnt/c/Users/Dot/Desktop/ai_files'" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/ai-safety-gridworlds" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an environment variable which will be visible for all users on Ubuntu you can create a sh file in /etc/profile.d folder.
In example :

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/my_vars.sh && sudo chmod o+r /etc/profile.d/my_vars.sh
```

then include there your variables. For example:

```
export ORACLE_HOME="/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2"
```

terminate and start wsl again. Variables should be accessible for all users.

Answer (score 0):

From root, you can run:

**nano .bashrc**

And then at the bottom, enter your command(s), e.g., in my case:

**sudo -S <<< "password" service redis-server restart**

This worked on Ubuntu as WSL on Windows 10